# Attack against stream cipher (LFSR with ASCII)

Tags: cryptanalysis, stream-cipher, known-plaintext-attack, lfsr

I'm reading Understanding Cryptography by Christof Paar and Jan Pelzl. In chapter 2 (Stream Ciphers) there's a question that goes like this:

> Assume we have a stream cipher whose period is quite short. We happen to
> know that the period is 150–200 bit in length. We assume that we do not know
> anything else about the internals of the stream cipher. In particular, we should not
> assume that it is a simple LFSR. For simplicity, assume that English text in ASCII
> format is being encrypted.

> Describe in detail how such a cipher can be attacked. Specify exactly what Oscar
> has to know in terms of plaintext/ciphertext, and how he can decrypt all ciphertext.

I'm assuming that a Known-Plaintext attack would work for this particular scenario. So, the attacker would have to know some plaintext. My question is could the plain-text be derived by performing LFA (Letter Frequency Analysis)? Since the question assume that English text in ASCII format is being encrypted ?  If not how can the attacker guess some of the plaintext ?

Or if Known-Plaintext is an infeasible attack what other attack could be feasible ?

Comment: If the period is small then you have some form of the Vigenere cipher.

Comment: I'm guessing that the question assumes that XOR is used for creating the ciphertext, and that it is as such not plaintext aware.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes that's what I assumed.